# How to exclude lan from routing

Tags: iptables, route

server1 - eth0 - 192.168.1.212 (192.168.1.0/24)
        - eth1 - 192.168.5.1 (192.168.5.0/24) --> router2 --> DSL

server2 - eth0 - 192.168.1.223 (192.168.1.0/24)
        - eth1 - 192.168.123.223 (192.168.123.0/24)

(DSL)router2 <--> server1 <--> server2

on server1

```
route add -net 192.168.123.0/24 gw 192.168.1.223 dev eth0
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.123.0/24 -d 0/0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -d 192.168.123.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

So, network 192.168.123.0/24 reachable 192.168.1.0/24 and router2 too. That's ok

I'd like deny network 192.168.123.0/24 to see all hosts on 192.168.1.0/24.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `iptables` by itself, I recommend that you use a firewall management package like Shorewall to configure the firewall. There you can easily configure different zones in your network, and configure access between them.

However, if you want to use `iptables` only, you add this line after your `route` command:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.123.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j REJECT
```